# Install angularjs2 in visual studio 2015 for web

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, angular, tsd

[image]i tried this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1026938/AngularJS-Getting-Started-with-Visual-Studio but when i do:

```
tsd query angular2 es6-promise rx rx-lite --action install
```

he not recognise sadd internal external batch

Comment: it's not very clear what you are asking. What do you mean with not recognize internal external batch? what error are you getting?

Comment: the error is that not recognize internal external batch

Comment: i add the error to my post

Comment: ah, that's easy to fix, you don't have tsd installed. run npm install -g tsd

Comment: or better look into typings.. I'll make an answer with it tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install **tsd** before you can use it to get .d.ts files.

Install it by running:

```
npm install -g tsd
```

You can find more about tsd [here](http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/).